# Can variables have synonyms?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, dictionary

I have very big string, which give me access to my dictionary in another dictionary in another class.

```
self.app_data.ip_table[self.app_data.cfg.MY_IP]['tasks']
```

If I used this dict in sequence of strings, I can write something like this (I think so):

```
with self.app_data:
    ...
```

But I use this variable in different lines in all file, I can't use `with` instruction. Than I think, in C++ we can use something like `#define VAR very.long.access.path.to.variable`.

Is there something like that in python? Can I shorter variable access name?

P.S.
That long-access-name variable changes with other thread. I don't need just assigned it to another variable. I'm looking for text-shorter for code

Comment: `a = self.app_data`…?

Comment: Read the documentation about `with`, it is not what you think... To make a synonym just assign the variable to some other variable with a shorter name, like `a = very.long.access.path.to.variable` and use `a`, then.

Comment: @deceze it can helps, but i must reassign variable `a` every time, coz that variable changes with other thread

Comment: When you say "the variable changes" do you mean that `self.app_data.ip_table[self.app_data.cfg.MY_IP]['tasks']` gets re-bound to an entirely different object, or that the object it references gets mutated?

Comment: @holdenweb no, it can't be rebound or mutuated

Comment: In which case, how exactly _does_ it change?

Comment: @holdenweb it move values between different items of dictionary. And i don't know if there is safe way to assigned it

Comment: @gek0n in principle, you can have multiple _names_ pointing out to same _value_. Now, depending on said value being mutable or not, you may expect different things to happen. In order to receive thoughtful answer, you need to create [MCVE] that shows how _long-access-name variable changes with other thread_ is actually accessed and changed. Right now I'd say question is really ambiguous.

Comment: I think you need to differentiate between a variable and an object.  In C++ you might say that a variable holds an object, but in python a variable is just a name which *refers* to an object - it is a reference, in crude terms like a `void *` only without the nastiness.  So as you know you can have more than one reference to any object, but also know that this will increase the reference count on the object, so be careful of a memory leak.

Comment: Incidentally: In C++ I'd reject a #define at code review.  `const auto& var = very.long.access.path.to.variable;` would be much nicer.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use properties maybe?

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.app_data = get_app_data()

    @property
    def var(self):
        return self.app_data.very['long'].path.here

    @var.setter
    def var(self, value):
        self.app_data.very['long'].path.here = value

c = C()
print c.var
c.var = 1337
```

Also you can create `var_threadsafe` property with a mutex inside if you expect this data to be read/written in multiple threads.